A unique problem -- Intensely long startup times kubuntu 22.04
I am not planning on quitting Kubuntu anytime soon, been using it for about 8 years as a daily driver. But I do take issue with my startup times on my desktop. See, I have a few other computers with various forms of GNU/Linux on them including one with the same version of Kubuntu that loads up much faster, and that baffles me because that laptop is over 10 years old and my hardware on my desktop (the one that is taking forever to boot up) has much newer parts.
Here is my systemd-analyze blame output. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can shorten my boot time?
6min 15.217s apport-autoreport.service
 53.010s mysql.service
 52.721s postgresql@12-main.service
 48.015s postgresql@14-main.service
 30.833s snapd.seeded.service
 28.589s snapd.service
 25.842s udisks2.service
 23.875s click-system-hooks.service
 19.195s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 18.352s cups.service
 17.788s accounts-daemon.service
 15.747s power-profiles-daemon.service
 15.712s polkit.service
 15.619s dev-sda5.device
 14.810s nginx.service
 13.797s resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
 13.741s avahi-daemon.service
 13.734s bluetooth.service
 13.730s NetworkManager.service
 13.711s dundee.service
 13.327s ofono.service
 12.326s thermald.service
 12.320s wpa_supplicant.service
 12.317s systemd-logind.service
 10.642s systemd-journal-flush.service
 10.312s smartmontools.service
  9.444s ModemManager.service
  8.451s dev-loop14.device
  8.336s systemd-modules-load.service
  7.379s dev-loop13.device
  7.377s teamviewerd.service
  7.259s dev-loop20.device
  7.222s dev-loop21.device
  6.937s dev-loop26.device
  6.795s dev-loop8.device
  6.705s dev-loop16.device
  6.674s dev-loop23.device
  6.578s dev-loop22.device
  6.509s dev-loop19.device
  6.164s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  6.158s dev-loop10.device
  6.078s dev-loop17.device
  6.073s dev-loop25.device
  5.939s systemd-sysusers.service
  5.651s dev-loop15.device
  5.346s dev-loop27.device
  5.315s dev-loop9.device
  5.162s gpu-manager.service
  4.984s dev-loop18.device
  4.980s dev-loop24.device
  4.802s dev-loop11.device
  4.750s dev-loop3.device
  4.606s dev-loop5.device
  4.416s dev-loop12.device
  4.181s dev-loop0.device
  4.079s dev-loop6.device
  3.910s dev-loop7.device
  3.713s apport.service
  3.623s packagekit.service
  3.616s networking.service
  3.542s dev-loop2.device
  3.490s apparmor.service
  3.465s dev-loop4.device
  3.385s snapd.apparmor.service
  3.308s dev-loop1.device
  3.013s grub-common.service
  2.789s systemd-udevd.service
  2.727s binfmt-support.service
  2.679s ondemand.service
  2.657s tlp.service
  2.498s systemd-resolved.service
  2.338s ua-timer.service
  2.090s postfix@-.service
  2.002s e2scrub_reap.service
  1.988s mountkernfs.service
  1.972s rc.local.service
  1.961s rsyslog.service
  1.925s virtualbox.service
  1.734s keyboard-setup.service
  1.648s lm-sensors.service
  1.460s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  1.438s colord.service
  1.337s systemd-udev-trigger.service
  1.154s gpsd.service
  1.138s systemd-sysctl.service
  1.003s apt-daily.service
   975ms snap-core18-2796.mount
   961ms snap-core18-2812.mount
   919ms user@1000.service
   830ms systemd-random-seed.service
   798ms qemu-kvm.service
   770ms webfs.service
   744ms snap-core22-1033.mount
   737ms snap-firefox-3941.mount
   707ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-264.mount
   655ms systemd-binfmt.service
   655ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
   655ms atd.service
   632ms snap-core22-1122.mount
   611ms systemd-timesyncd.service
   600ms setvtrgb.service
   575ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-141.mount
   550ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-140.mount
   546ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
   529ms snap-bare-5.mount
   517ms snap-gaming\x2dgraphics\x2dcore22-154.mount
   512ms snap-chromium-2805.mount
   509ms snap-chromium-2811.mount
   502ms ufw.service
   467ms kerneloops.service
   454ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-edf0d0eb\x2d60a1\x2d4c6e\x2d8359\x2d526683b0584b.swap
   445ms systemd-journald.service
   435ms snap-core20-2182.mount
   435ms openvpn.service
   433ms snap-core20-2264.mount
   428ms console-setup.service
   390ms snap-snapd-21184.mount
   389ms snap-shortwave-83.mount
   384ms snap-cups-1024.mount
   377ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   361ms sddm.service
   356ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-198.mount
   318ms dns-clean.service
   315ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount
   307ms plymouth-start.service
   284ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   280ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-194.mount
   277ms snap-shortwave-87.mount
   276ms mountdevsubfs.service
   275ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   270ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   236ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-172.mount
   230ms snap-firefox-4090.mount
   227ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
   213ms snap-cups-1041.mount
   200ms lvm2-monitor.service
   190ms dev-hugepages.mount
   189ms dev-mqueue.mount
   186ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   185ms update-notifier-download.service
   184ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   176ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   173ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   168ms modprobe@configfs.service
   166ms modprobe@drm.service
   162ms upower.service
   161ms modprobe@fuse.service
   130ms snap-gaming\x2dgraphics\x2dcore22-166.mount
   128ms mnt-f269f04f\x2d22b5\x2d4d5e\x2d9210\x2d1744425f9650.mount
   127ms ifupdown-pre.service
   127ms snap-snapd-20671.mount
    91ms rtkit-daemon.service
    58ms plymouth-read-write.service
    45ms mountnfs.service
    27ms plymouth-quit.service
    26ms alsa-restore.service
    25ms checkroot.service
    25ms checkfs.service
    18ms run-qemu.mount
    18ms checkroot-bootclean.service
    18ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
    17ms mountall.service
    16ms mountall-bootclean.service
    14ms bootmisc.service
    11ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
    10ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
     9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     9ms mountnfs-bootclean.service
     9ms ureadahead-stop.service
     6ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
     4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
     3ms snapd.socket
     2ms postgresql.service
   110us blk-availability.service

I haven't even installed Linux on this PC in 8 years. I've replaced parts, cloned old hard drives to new ones, so on and so forth but I've got a bunch of files on here still that are from 8 years ago and even some stuff from my Windows 7 days. I am sure this probably has something to do with it but am squeamish about doing a fresh install...I've upgraded from Kubuntu every two years (for the LTS releases) without any problems thus far except for this slow startup issue I've had that seems to get worse with time. I would like to see if I can load up in like 2 minutes or less, but I don't know how practical that goal is. It's very normal on my other GNU/Linux systems to boot up in less than a minute, but this desktop has a hard time getting ready when I boot it up and has for years.
Keep in mind that the apport process doesn't prevent me from using my desktop, I find that there are always one or two processes that are still running in the background for several minutes after I get to loading my programs, etc.
P.S. I am not using any SSD drives. I have one of those FireCuda hybrid solid state drives (new old stock, just started using it) as my main hard drive and a 7200rpm drive as my secondary (also new old stock).
p.s. someone asked if I could upload my systemd-analyze time. Well here it is:
  Startup finished in 46.778s (kernel) + 6min 52.063s (userspace) = 7min 38.842s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 40.828s in userspace

results of systemd-analyze critical-chain:
graphical.target @1min 40.828s
└─multi-user.target @1min 40.827s
  └─whoopsie.service @6min 21.969s
    └─network-online.target @1min 6.981s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @47.784s +19.195s
        └─NetworkManager.service @34.048s +13.730s
          └─dbus.service @34.040s
            └─basic.target @33.989s
              └─sockets.target @33.989s
                └─snapd.socket @33.979s +3ms
                  └─sysinit.target @33.577s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @32.965s +611ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @26.468s +6.164s
                        └─local-fs.target @26.356s
                          └─run-user-1000-doc.mount @3min 35.462s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @2min 43.477s
                              └─swap.target @26.335s
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-edf0d0eb\x2d60a1\x2d4c6e\x2d8359\x2d526683b0584>
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-edf0d0eb\x2d60a1\x2d4c6e\x2d8359\x2d526683b05>


What's the actual startup time? Can you post the output of systemd-analyze time? Anyways I'll just put this out there: despite what people might have been saying as of lately, KDE is still the only thing that can cripple startup on my otherwise still blazing fast second machine running Arch (for reference we're talking Core i5-2400, same machine with GNOME is up MUCH faster).

I will add my systemd-analyze time results to my original post. It says it takes a whopping 7 minutes.

Sorry, maybe systemd-analyze critical-chain would be more helpful here.

okay, sure, I will add that right now as well.

RIght, network is taking quite a bit to come up (13 + 19 seconds if I'm interpreting correctly), however it seems as though the culprit is after graphical.target; not sure how to pragmatically go about debugging that. Do you have any startup scripts / programs that run on startup that may hindering boot times?

What does journalctl -u apport.service say? I'm not sure if that could be blocking, but it's taking a long time to come up...

The only startup program that I have is Akregator (RSS Feed reader) but I only configured that as a startup program maybe 2-3 months ago. Could it have anything to do with my graphics card being old? My GPU was manufactured in 2018 it's a Radeon RX580. I'm using the FOSS drivers xorg-whatever-it-is-radeon. I've got two fresh, unused hard drives, 2 sticks of ram that are also unused NIB but probably a few years old. new CPU fan. Cleaned the whole thing's innards from top to bottom over the weekend with a make-up brush and cleaning alcohol.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
